# TextInputLayout with new support for character counting

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-textinputlayout

I read out new blog post of android-developers [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html).

> [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html?utm_campaign=android_update_important_bug_fixes_101515&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog)
>   expands its existing functionality of floating hint text and error
>   indicators with new support for [character counting](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-character-counter).

But I can't find any programmatically code support for *character counting*.
I want some code to implementation of *character counting* using `TextInputLayout`

Comment: Have you looked at `TextWatcher` and added this to your `AppCompatEditText` ? which will help you perform character counting on the fly without using the `TextInputLayout` directly

Comment: below answer helped what I am using `TextInputLayout` with normal `EditText` .Thanks @inner_class7 for your reply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a new [`setCounterEnabled(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setCounterEnabled(boolean)) method that you can use to enable the character counter.

It simply displays the current character count inside the view.